# sc.TextFile("") working in Eclipse but not in a JAR

Tags: eclipse, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I'm writing a code which will be in a hadoop cluster but before all, I test it locally  with local files. The code is working great in Eclipse but when I'm making a huge JAR with SBT (with spark lib etc) the program is working until a `textFile(path)` my code is :

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer




object TestCRA2 {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("Test")
      .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
    val context = new SparkContext(conf)//.master("local")
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    def TimeParse1(path: String) : RDD[(Int,Long,Long)] = {
        val data = context.textFile(path).map(_.split(";"))
        return data
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val data = TimeParse1("file:///home/quentin/Downloads/CRA") 
    }
}
```

And here is my error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: file
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.hadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:830)
    at main.scala.TestCRA2$.TimeParse1(TestCRA.scala:37)
    at main.scala.TestCRA2$.main(TestCRA.scala:84)
    at main.scala.TestCRA2.main(TestCRA.scala)
```

I can't put my files into the JAR cause they are in the cluster hadoop and it's working on Eclipse.

Here is my build.sbt :

```
name := "BloomFilters"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"


libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.3"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

If I don't do my `assemblyMergeStrategy` like this I've got bunch of errors of merging.

Actually I needed to change my `build.sbt` like this :

```
name := "BloomFilters"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.3"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
      (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {

        case "services" :: xs => MergeStrategy.first

        case _ => MergeStrategy.discard
 }
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Thank you @lyomi

Comment: how did you run the jar file?

Comment: `java -jar BloomFilters-assembly-1.0.jar`

Comment: You have to use spark-submit i guess

Comment: Nope because I'm local not in my cluster. It's working with Eclipse actually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sbt assembly` is probably ignoring some of the required files. Specifically, Hadoop's `FileSystem` class relies on a service discovery mechanism that looks for ALL `META-INFO/services/org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` files in the classpath.

On Eclipse it was fine, because each JAR had the corresponding file, but in the uber-jar one might have overridden others, causing the `file:` scheme to not get recognized.

In your SBT settings, add the following, to concatenate the service discovery files instead of discarding some of them.

```
val defaultMergeStrategy: String => MergeStrategy = { 
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
      // ... possibly other settings ...
      case "services" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
  }
  case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
}
```

See [README.md of sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) for more info.